# Get the mean of timedelta column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column made of timedelta elements in a dataframe:

```
       time_to_return_ask
0       0 days 00:00:00.046000
1       0 days 00:00:00.204000
2       0 days 00:00:00.336000
3       0 days 00:00:00.362000
4       0 days 00:00:00.109000
                 ...          
3240    0 days 00:00:00.158000
3241    0 days 00:00:00.028000
3242    0 days 00:00:00.130000
3243    0 days 00:00:00.035000
3244                         0
Name: time_to_return_ask, Length: 3245, dtype: object
```

I tried to apply the solution of another question, by taking the values of the different elements, but I am already stuck. Any idea? Thanks!

What I tried:

```
df['time_to_return_ask'].values.astype(np.int64)
means = dropped.groupby('ts').mean()
means['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(means['new'])
```

Comment: `df['time_to_return_ask'].mean()` works for me, make sure the column is a time delta column `df['time_to_return_ask'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_to_return_ask'])`

Comment: you're right, `pd.to_timedelta(df['time_to_return_ask']).mean()`, worked